# Is there something wrong with the way I am implementing sendkeys?

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

Why does sendkeys not work here?

The website I am practicing on is https://www.cineplex.com/

```
@Test 
    public void testLogin() {
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.cineplex.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("meta-nav-menu--account")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click(); // work up to here
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'txtEmailAddress\']")).sendKeys("radsfsad"); // username login
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"txtPassword\"]")).sendKeys("afdsa");// pass login
    
    }
```

[The inspect code for entering email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYDcu.png)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax seems to be incorrect, you can try:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("txtEmailAddress")).sendKeys("radsfsad");
driver.findElement(By.id("txtEmailAddress")).sendKeys("afdsa");
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='txtEmailAddress']")).sendKeys("radsfsad"); // username login

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='txtPassword']")).sendKeys("afdsa");// pass login
```

Comment: I have tried both and they both still have the same error. The error is saying unable to locate element for txtEmailAddress.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explicitwait`

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(20));

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("txtEmailAddress"))).sendKeys("Youlrogin");

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("txtPassword"))).sendKeys("YourPassword")
```

I am unable to access the url so make sure there is no iframe, in case of iframe you have to first `switch()` to the frame and then use the above statement